# What do I have to set to see screenviews from app and webview in the same flow in behavior flow?

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In our app we have native and WebView parts.

WebView elements open our website (which is SPA).

We want to track in behavior flow tab that users go through certain app screens than WebView screens than again native app screens.

What we currently see are two separated flows that share nothing, but correctly start from iOS, one with native app screenviews one with WebView screenviews.

Everything was set according to 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens

It looks like ga is set correctly because in User Explorer tab,
for choosen user all screenviews are in proper order but also don't seem to be part of the same flow (there is black line beteween native and webview screenviews).

Is there anything more that should be set? 
Or maybe it's some kind of setting inside user interface of google analytics?